# AS3 the on/off menu wont work

Tags: actionscript-3

I wanted to make a menu, when it was not there, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open it, when it was there, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close it. but this wont work, it show this error:

1176: Comparison between a value with static type `flash.text:TextField` and a possibly unrelated type `String`.

This is my code

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, down);
function down(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    var keyPressed:String = "";
    keyPressed = keyEvent.keyCode.toString();
    if (keyPressed == "27")
    {
        if (now == "0")
        {
            menu._x = 100;
            now.text = "1";
        }
        else if (now == "1")
        {
            menu._x = -400;
            now.text = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `now` is a `TextField` you need to compare its `text` property

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, down);
function down(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE)
    {
        if (now.text == "0")
        {
            menu._x = 100;
            now.text = "1";
        }
        else if (now.text == "1")
        {
            menu._x = -400;
            now.text = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

You can also set `visible` to `false/true` to hide show the menu instead of moving it off the stage. I also changed the keyCode to use the `Keyboard` class.